# Greasemonkey snapshot outdated after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

**Scenario:** Writing a Greasemonkey script which hides Twitter comments (indicated by list element with class "class-TWEET") on BBC live sports reports.

I've managed to get something which roughly works (caveats below), using waitForKeyElements:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        myName
// @namespace   none
// @description myDescription
// @include     http://www.bbc.co.uk/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @version     2.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function doHousekeeping(jNode) {

//Find all tweet items within the commentary, and hide them
var snapResults = document.evaluate(".//div[@id='live-event-text-commentary']/ol/li[contains(@class,'class-TWEET')]", document.body, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for (var i = snapResults.snapshotLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      snapResults.snapshotItem(i).style.display="none"; 
  }
}

// Cleanup on initial load
doHousekeeping();

// Repeat cleanup whenever the main body changes
waitForKeyElements ("#live-event-text-commentary", doHousekeeping);
```

**Problem:** When the page refreshes, doHousekeeping *does* execute (and hides *most* of the offending items); however, a handful of the most recent offending items still remain at the top of the page.

Why is it failing to hide all of them? My suspicion is that the document/snapshot is somehow not being refreshed when the body changes. Also I'm new to jQuery, so I'm aware that my housekeeping function is both old-school and sub-optimal; any help for a cleaner, fully-functional implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that there is a mismatch between what you want hidden and the selector given to `waitForKeyElements`.

The correct way to use `waitForKeyElements` in this case is like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        myName
// @namespace   none
// @description myDescription
// @include     http://www.bbc.co.uk/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @version     2.0
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

//-- Find all tweet items within the commentary, and hide them.
waitForKeyElements (
    "#live-event-text-commentary ol li.class-TWEET",
    doHousekeeping
);

function doHousekeeping (jNode) {
    jNode.hide ();
}
```

Also, don't use `@grant none`, as this can cause flaky side effects.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I knew I was throwing too much complexity at the problem.